# Looking for a Webapp that combines the power of Smartsheets and Trello

Tags: webapp-rec

I run a business that involves me managing client profiles and regularly performing actions associated with their accounts (i.e. taking care of forms, taxes, communications from different parties associated with the account).

I thought Smartsheets would be ideal because it's so easy and clean to manage data with it. However I soon discovered that managing workflow and determining where things were up to, what was in progress, what needed to be done etc was a mess.

Then I tried Trello. Trello was incredible when it came to workflow and project management. "Cards" would easily moved and classified. At one glance, I or my partners could see what was where and what was due when. However, I soon saw the difficulty of keeping client info in the "card" descriptions as opposed to lists, and the pain it was to manually enter data instead of populating them from web forms.

I am looking for an online database that essentially combines the power of Smartsheet and Trello in that it has a really clean intuitive project management space backed up by a coherent spreadsheet based database.

Until Trello and Smartsheets merge, I need another option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've got it!

The answer is ZOHO Projects! It's fantastic, and I've adopted it.

Zoho Projects offers what can be described as an all encompassing business data, task management and collaboration tool that is designed in the style of a social network. Your homepage consists of a news feed much like Facebook's, consisting of all the recent activity that has taken place in your projects. You can proceed to go into any project (which could each represent a client, as it does in my case) or select the task menu and see all the tasks - from across ALL projects - currently assigned to you.

I have fallen in love with this system. The only downside is it's a bit pricey at $500 a year for the full version, but for the level of support and high quality software, not to mention brilliant functionalities, it's quite worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Other suggestions are:
Assembla, Asana and Redmine. The last one refers to a tool, in the sense that you will have to find the hosting for it. There are a few paid hosting providers and I know of one [free one](https://www.hostedredmine.com/) which you can use to try it and decide if you go for a paid one (recommended in case you use it to interface clients)

Answer (score -1):

I think [ProofHub](http://www.proofhub.com) would be the best for you. I am sure that it contains all the features that are present in Smartsheet and Trello + it has both free as well as paid packages. I’ve been using this tool for the past 2 months and it has eased my work a lot.

Comment: If you are affiliated with proofhub in any way, you should disclose it.